# Getting error message about master.sys.sysclsobjs while converting SQL Server database to Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure

I have SQL Server 2008 R2 (v10.50.2500) and a database with compatibility level SQL Server 2000. I am trying to "export data-tier application" to export this database to MS Azure. And I am getting an error:

> Error 0: An error occurred while attempting to reverse engineer elements of type Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SchemaModel.SqlCredential:
>   Batch Command during reverse engineer failed with Error Code: -2146232060 Line Number: 16 Error Message: Invalid object name 'master.sys.sysclsobjs'.

What should I do to fix it?

Comment: Azure does not support SQL Server 2000. The oldest version that [Azure supports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-2017#arguments) is compatibility level 100; SQL server 2000 is level 80. You will need to ensure updated to an appropriate compatibility before you can migrate it.

Comment: Extra note: SQL Server 2008 has about 4 weeks left of support, so I would not be surprised is support for level 100 is removed from Azure not too long afterwards. After you have got to level 100 (maximum on SQL Server 2008 R2), I would look to getting to a higher level again; you should be aiming for a minimum of 110 in my opinion but higher *if* you can. I don't suggest planning to use level 100 in Azure permanently, as support likely will disappear.

Comment: You want to export your master database to Microsoft Azure storage, but you get the error. Can you show us some columns and data  about the table  master.sys.sysclsobjs?

Comment: I am not exporting "master" database. And I cannot see "sys.sysclsobjs" in my "master" database.

Comment: ...and compatibility level of the "master" database is 100. but, again, I am not exporting "master".

Comment: @user3565412 I also could not see the 'master.sys.sysclsobjs'  in my local SQL Server. I'm just confused that if you are exporting other database, why it contain the 'master.sys.sysclsobjs' schema?  Can please you show us some steps or pictures?

Comment: Please check the  export data-tier application:  Export setting--advanced, select the tables for export manually.

Comment: `sys.sysclsobjs` is a system table. It exists even today in the most recent versions of SQL Server (its presence is shielded from user-mode queries, but can be seen with `select * from sys.objects where name = 'sysclsobjs'`). The DACPAC export has no real business referencing it; I suspect a bug/compatibility issue in the code for some old/unexpected construct in the database.

Comment: You may have more success using [SSDT](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt) and manually importing the database into a project. This may either fail with the same error, or it may succeed and give a database project that can then be built and scanned for invalid logins/views/procedures that are "not a problem" for a live database but prevent creation of a data-tier application.

Comment: Alternatively, try the [Data Migration Assistant](https://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=53595) (disclaimer: no experience), which has the ability to detect issues that prevent migration.

Comment: I imported a database to SQL server 2012 (on Azure virtual machine) and then successfully exported it to Azure. How can I mark 1st comment as an answer?

Comment: Hi @user3565412,  I summarized Larnu's commnet  and post it as the answer, you can mark it and let others know your error is solved by Larnu's help.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for Larnu's comments:

1. Azure does not support SQL Server 2000. The oldest version that [Azure supports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-2017#arguments) is compatibility level 100; SQL server 2000 is level 80. You will need to ensure updated to an appropriate compatibility before you can migrate it.
2. Extra note: SQL Server 2008 has about 4 weeks left of support, so I would not be surprised is support for level 100 is removed from Azure not too long afterwards. After you have got to level 100 (maximum on SQL Server 2008 R2), I would look to getting to a higher level again; you should be aiming for a minimum of 110 in my opinion but higher if you can. I don't suggest planning to use level 100 in Azure permanently, as support likely will disappear.

According these comments Larnu provided for us, he(she) pointed out the reason and help you solved the error. You imported a database to SQL server 2012 (on Azure virtual machine) and then successfully exported it to Azure.

Thanks Larnu again.